# Как добиться асинхронности от getter?

Tags: vue.js

У меня проблема.
Есть action в котором я делаю запрос.

```
api.getList().then((res) =>  {
      state.Forms = res.data 
      commit("createStructure");
  });
```

В мутации собственно меняю state.
Есть getter на данное свойство.

Проблема в том, что когда в компоненте я обращаюсь к геттеру.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["actualForms"]),
  }
```

,

Сначала обрабатывается он ( пустой) а потом приходит ответ с сервера.
Пробовал сделать и в created и в mounted. Результат один

Как сделать чтобы сначала дождаться инфомрации с бэка, а потом отрисовать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как там у вас store структурирован. Но самый простой способ это добавить в него флаг того, был ли выполнен запрос к API или нет и вообще не грузить компонент с геттером пока там `false`.

Это даст вам:

1. возможность не грузить компонент сразу, а подгрузить его асинхронно после того как данные придут (более быстрая загрузка вашего приложения);
2. как-то показать пользователю, что данные грузятся. Например, отрисовав скелетончик на месте где вы в будущем отрисуете компонент (красиво покажете пользователю, что тут скоро что-то будет);
3. обработать ошибку, вдруг ваш сервер не ответит и тогда вы вообще не будете грузить компонент с геттером и отрисуете другой, в котором будет информация об ошибке.